# Objects being deformed when in rendered view

Tags: rendering

I built the scene using EEVEE render engine. Now I'm changing to cycles to get a more realistic scene. Though when I go in rendered view, all the objects are being deformed in weird ways. Even those with no modifier are being deformed. Is there something I'm missing here? I've applied the scale to everything as well.

[image]

[image]

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KH0PIg_iS_uwfC4A-2Vv2LPLHDDuCj6Q

Comment: Could you share the blend file?

Comment: Here ya go! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eI_7SsiltaRknPwahqxhVaqISpf-cRKo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, I think that I found the issue, but I need the textures, could you export it like this Blender-> File -> External Data -> Automatically pack into .blend (click to activate) and save the file again.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to having a look at it! https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KH0PIg_iS_uwfC4A-2Vv2LPLHDDuCj6Q

Answer (score 1):

In each material that have a bump node go to settings (on the material tab) → surface and change displace only to bump only. Then enter edit mode and come back to object mode to refresh the bump.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! That seems to have fixed my problem! Have a great day!

Comment: @ZacharyLabrie Don't just post "thank you" as a comment. If an answer helped you up vote it, and if it completely solved your problem consider marking it as accepted.